# Reverse Geocoding using Google Maps API

Tags: python, pandas, api, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am currently web **scraping** a real estate brokerage site and I want to perform some analysis based on each council of the district I'm **scraping**.

I am using a df.groupby(['Council']).mean() methodology, but i noticed that there are plenty of houses that are nearby but display different strings for the same council, thus complicating the mentioned analysis.

Therefore I was thinking of extracting the coordinates and reverse geocode through the Google maps API to get a standardized council, enabling the 'groupby' methodology.

I have no idea how to reverse geocode, so I would greatly appreciate your help. A representative dataframe is accessible through the following code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Latitude': [38.767576, 38.741316, 38.735412, 38.777123], 'Longitude': [-9.104245, -9.146489, -9.145569, -9.095273]})
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing things away like rubbish.

Comment: You can check the Google Maps - Geocoding API reverse geocoding [sample here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#ReverseGeocoding)